# dired: is file under point local or remote?

Tags: dired, files, tramp, remote

In a dired buffer, how can I determine whether the file under the point, i.e. `(dired-get-file-for-visit)`, is local or remote?  Is there something like `(dired-local-file-p)` or maybe `(tramp-local-file-p file)`?

I would like to call different functions for visiting local and remote files.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you get remote files listed in a Dired buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to know whether the file is accessed through a remote acces method, you can call [`file-remote-p`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Magic-File-Names.html#index-file_002dremote_002dp-2047) (built into Emacs) or Tramp's similar function `tramp-handle-file-remote-p`. Both functions return `nil` for an actual file name and the method prefix (as a string) for a file accessed through a remote method.

This may or may not be what you're after. Files on a remote filesystem mounted by the operating system (NFS, Samba, Windows shares, SSHFS, etc.) will be reported as nil; you can [call `df` to get more information](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/397) if you have unix tools available. Contrariwise, local files accessed through privilege escalation (e.g. `/sudo::` or `/su::`) are reported as non-nil. You can call `tramp-dissect-file-name` and the `tramp-file-name-…` function family (all defined in `tramp.el`) if you want to analyze the method further.

Comment: `file-remote-p` is exactly what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I realize you're asking to detect tramp buffers vs, say, files on a remote mounted filesystem, but for posterity this might be useful to other searchers:

```
(defun buffer-is-on-local-fs-p ()
  (and (buffer-file-name)
       (let ((local-path (chomp (shell-command-to-string
                                 (concat "df -l \"" (buffer-file-name) "\" | awk '/^Filesystem/ {next}; {print $6}'")))))
         (not (string= "" local-path)))))
```

This uses unix's `df` to identify the filesystem hosting the full path of the current buffer, and then makes a best-effort to determine what its mount type is. It's not perfect, but it's served me pretty well (I used to use it to gate VC mode funcionality, which was painfully slow on remote filesystems).

Comment: For the case at hand I was looking for a way to determine the "remoteness" of a file *before* opening it, i.e. there is no buffer associated with it (yet).  Still, your trick is pretty neat!

Comment: The trick can work without a path; note that it uses `buffer-file-name` to extract a filename, but you could just as easily pass in a path and use that.